# If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact connected and $Cl(Int(A))=A$ must there be a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$ that takes $A$ to the unit disk?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a compact connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $A=Cl(Int(A))$. Must there exist a homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\phi(A)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|\leq 1\}$? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this error. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The closure of the bounded domain bounded by the [Warsaw circle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle) is a counter-example.